# Custom Windows Workflow activity that executes an asynchronous operation - redone using generic service

Tags: asynchronous, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am writing a custom Windows Workflow Foundation activity, that starts some process asynchronously, and then should wake up when an async event arrives.

All the samples I’ve found (e.g. [this one by Kirk Evans](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2007/07/02/asynchronous-workflow-activities-implemented-asynchronous-webrequests.aspx)) involve a custom workflow service, that does most of the work, and then posts an event to the activity-created queue. The main reason for that seems to be that the only method to post an event [that works from a non-WF thread] is WorkflowInstance.EnqueueItem, and the activities don’t have access to workflow instances, so they can't post events (from non-WF thread where I receive the result of async operation).

I don't like this design, as this splits functionality into two pieces, and requires adding a service to a host when a new activity type is added. Ugly.

So I wrote the following generic service that I call from the activity’s async event handler, and that can reused by various async activities (error handling omitted):

```
class WorkflowEnqueuerService : WorkflowRuntimeService
{
    public void EnqueueItem(Guid workflowInstanceId, IComparable queueId, object item)
    {
        this.Runtime.GetWorkflow(workflowInstanceId).EnqueueItem(queueId, item, null, null);
    }
}
```

Now in the activity code, I can obtain and store a reference to this service, start my async operation, an when it completes, use this service to post an event to my queue. The benefits of this - I keep all the activity-specific code inside activity, and I don't have to add new services for each activity types.

But seeing the official and internet samples doing it will specialized non-reusable services, I would like to check if this approach is OK, or I’m creating some problems here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential problem here with regard to workflow persistence.

If you create long running worklfows that are persisted in a database to the runtime will be able to restart these workflows are not reloaded into memory until there is some external event that reloads them. As there they are responsible for triggering the event themselves but cannot until they are reloaded. And we have a catch 22 :-(

The proper way to do this is using an external service. And while this might feel like dividing the code into two places it really isn't. The reason is that the workflow is responsible for the big picture, IE what should be done. And the runtime service is responsible for the actual implementation or how it should be done. That way you can change the how without changing the why and when part.

Answer (score 0):

A followup - regardless of all the reasons, why it "should be done" using a service, this will be directly supported by .NET 4.0, which provides a clean way for an activity to start an asynchronous work, while suspending the persistence of the activity.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.codeactivitycontext.setupasyncoperationblock(VS.100).aspx
for details.